# Invalid data when using struct with DynamicData attribute in MSTest testing?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I use MSTest.Framework/MSTest.TestAdapter 2.2.10.

I'm trying to pass test data to `Test_Method` by using `DynamicData` attribute. When `MyDateTime` is **struct** and I debug `Test_Method`, the `_date` field of `testData` has wrong date. But, when I change `MyDateTime` to **class**, then I get the correct date. What can be the problem? Is there any issue with boxing/unboxing of my `MyDateTime`?

```
[TestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(DataForTestMethod), DynamicDataSourceType.Property)]
public void Test_Method(MyDateTime testData)
{
}

public struct MyDateTime
{
    private DateTime _date;

    public MyDateTime(DateTime dt)
    {
        _date = dt;
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<object[]> DataForTestMethod
{
    get
    {
        var dt = new DateTime(2022,04,30,21,04,22);
        var myDate = new MyDateTime(dt);
        yield return new object[] { myDate };
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. Your update help me, thank you. Would be nice if you write this as an answer to your own question. That would be the stackoverflow-way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time with a .net decompiler, it seems that a struct should implement `ISerializable` interface for the MSTest framework to correctly return data through `DynamicDataAttribute`. The body of `ISerializable.GetObjectData` can even be empty(!). I cannot find what code is responsible for loading `DynamicDataAttribute` to explain this, but it seems to work if I just add `ISerializable` interface.

Comment: For those interested in some more details:
It looks like the test discovery behavior has changed in MSTest.TestAdapter/Framework 2.2.4:
https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/903

Also, there is an out-out of this behavior:
https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/issues/905